# Swift UIAccessibility to know the previously focused element?

Tags: swift, uiaccessibility

I was digging into UIAccessibility APIs but can't find any, is there a way to know the previously focused element? or is there is function that provide where the focusing is coming from?

For example, I am moving focus from element A to element B, is there any way to know that the previous element is A?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by element you mean a UIView ?

Comment: @MohmmadS basically any UIelement, like label, button etc.

Comment: thought about setting a flag ?

Comment: @MohmmadS here is the thing, say I have a UIView, and it has 3 different subviews, I want to know when the focus in entering the uiview, and when it's leaving the uiview. I can't really do this with a flag because say I am focused on child A, how do I know if next second I am going to move to a different UIcompoenent, or child B? I can capture this only by I know on a global level that an accessibility focus changed. There is one way to go about flag, so  I set flag on every single child, even then there is going to be race condition.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some portion of life digging and asking around, came up with a work around.
So two ways:
1. Extend UIView and override didbecameFosued, keep a reference on last focused element, since everything is a UIView

2. Add observer for element focused notification. Do the processing in selector.